# How can you control the order of SQL updates in EF6 DB model using TPT inheritance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, inheritance

Given the following classes ...

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string RandomValue { get; set; }
}
```

... which are mapped to SQL tables tblBaseClass and tblInheritedClass respectively using a TPT inheritance strategy in EF6.

When I create a record using the following code ...

```
var newClass = new InheritedClass {
    RandomValue = "Some Random Text",
    LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now
};

dbContext.InheritedClasses.Add(newClass);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

... data is inserted into the tblBaseClass first and then tblInheritedClass. However when I update a record similarly using ...

```
var existingClass = dbContext.InheritedClasses.Find(someKeyValue);
existingClass.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
existingClass.RandomValue = "Some Different Random Text";
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The tables are updated in reverse order (specifically, tblInheritedClass is updated and then tblBaseClass is updated).

**Question**

How can I specify that I want the base classes table to be updated first in this scenario? I am creating a trigger in the database on the inherited table to keep track of value changes, however I need to reference the date in the base table when I do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can specify a save order

> When you call SaveChanges, all entities are ordered from an internal
>   order in the method “ProduceDynamicCommands” then sorted again by the
>   method “TryTopologicalSort” which loop to add command with no
>   predecessor left (if you add A and B and A depend of B, then B will be
>   inserted before A)

There is no way you can specify an order unless you override **A LOT** of internal method (I had to do it to develop a BulkSaveChanges feature).